# How to grab a logged entry out of ELMAH manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, logging, elmah

This seems simple enough. Elmah logs the errors, I see the error in the elmah.axd file, I then want to grab the data out into a new custom view.

I can't figure out how to grab the Detail Page out of Elma. Thus far all ive been able to do is get the ErrorLogEntry I want but cannot figure out how to get the actual XML/Exception error the server spit out.

Elmah is set up normally. But I have:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"></error>
</customErrors>
```

Which goes to my simple ErrorController.cs class:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index( )
{
    Exception ex = null;

    try
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLogDataSourceAdapter eldsa = new Elmah.ErrorLogDataSourceAdapter( );
        ErrorLogEntry[] errors = eldsa.GetErrors( 0, 1 );

        foreach ( ErrorLogEntry ele in errors )
        {
            ViewData[ "Description" ] += ele.Error.Message + "<br />";
            ViewData[ "Description" ] += ele.Error.WebHostHtmlMessage + "<br />";
            Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory pf = new ErrorLogPageFactory( );

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewData[ "Description" ] = "An error occurred.";
    }

    ViewData[ "Title" ] = "Oops. We're sorry. An error occurred and we're on the case.";

    //Email.SendException( ex, "Error in PRISM.NET" );
    return View( );
}
```

The problem that occurs is that WebHostHtmlMessage is empty. So I cant get the Exception message.

I've been looking inside Elmah code all day and I can't figure out how to manually create a page just like it Elmah does when elmah.axd is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being as follows:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index( )
{
    Exception ex = null;

    try
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLogDataSourceAdapter eldsa = new Elmah.ErrorLogDataSourceAdapter( );
        ErrorLogEntry[] errors = eldsa.GetErrors( 0, 1 );

        foreach ( ErrorLogEntry ele in errors )
        {
            ErrorLogEntry thisError = ErrorLog.GetError(ele.Id);
            ex = new Exception( thisError.Error.WebHostHtmlMessage );
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewData[ "Description" ] = "An error occurred.";
    }

    ViewData[ "Description" ] = "Oops. We're sorry. An error occurred and we're on the case.";

    Email.SendException( ex, "Error in PRISM.NET" );
    return View( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the data in the default table ELMAH_Error

```
SELECT AllXml
FROM ELMAH_Error
```

Comment: Rather I want to grab the data out of the Elmah class not do it the old fashioned way.